# Translate an html5 canvas example to svg

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I got familiarize with canvas with the help of lot of resources available online, and trying to compare the same with svg. My application needs to draw limited number of shapes, but need to be interactive. I think svg would be more suitable being the shapes are dom elements. it would be great help if someone can translate the canvas example (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg3Cc/)) to svg with only dependency on jQuery and html5 (don't worry about IE)

In the example, I need to draw a rectangle using mouse (left click and drag). you may add each element to the dom  (in canvas I may have to keep an array for the rect object, as the screen clears on each event).

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="cvs" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
</body>
<    /html>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cvs = $("#cvs"),
        ctx = cvs.get(0).getContext("2d");
    var v_bufX, v_bufY, v_bufW, v_bufH;

    var box = function ( ctx, style, x, y, w, h ) {        
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect( x, y, w, h );
            ctx.closePath();
            if ( style.fill ) {
                ctx.fillStyle = style.fill;
                ctx.fill();
            }
            if ( style.stroke ) {
                ctx.strokeStyle = style.stroke;
                ctx.lineWidth = style.width || 1;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        },
        draw = function (res) {
            var style = {fill:'rgba(96,185,206, 0.3)',stroke:'rgb(96,185,206)',width:.5};
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); 
            box(ctx, style, res.x, res.y, res.w, res.h);
        };

    var rect = {
        reset : function () {
            this.x0 = this.y0 = this.x = this.y = this.w = this.h = -1;
            this.started = this.dragging = false;
        },    
        mousedown : function (e) {
            this.reset();
            this.started = true;
            this.x0 = e._x;
            this.y0 = e._y; 
        },
        mousemove : function (e) {
          if (!this.started) {
            return;     
          }

          var x = Math.min(e._x,  this.x0),
              y = Math.min(e._y,  this.y0),
              w = Math.abs(e._x - this.x0),
              h = Math.abs(e._y - this.y0);
         console.log(x, y, w, h);

          if (!w || !h) {
          return;       
          };
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.w = w;
          this.h = h;
          draw(this);
        },
        mouseup : function (ev) {
          if (this.started) {
            this.mousemove(ev);
            this.started = false;
            draw(this);
          }
        }
    };


    $(window).mousedown(function(e) {       
        var canvasOffset = cvs.offset();
        e._x = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left); 
        e._y = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
        rect.mousedown(e);          
    }); 
    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
        var canvasOffset = cvs.offset();
        e._x = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left); 
        e._y = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
        rect.mousemove(e);
    });
    $(window).mouseup(function(e) {
        var canvasOffset = cvs.offset();
        e._x = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left); 
        e._y = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
        rect.mouseup(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What parts are you finding difficult? Can you create a static SVG file? Embed it in HTML or XHTML? Run JavaScript within it? Create elements procedurally? Create or re-use a dragging function? Asking someone to write a fair amount of custom code for you is not (in my humble opinion) in the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's an example of [embedding SVG in XHTML5](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml), including using JavaScript to create elements dynamically. Here's an example of [dragging elements in custom transformation spaces](http://phrogz.net/SVG/drag_under_transformation.xhtml).

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Today I started learning svg, but couldn't find much material initially.. also things were changed with html5. I also put some effort in this question as I wrote the demo. I thought seeing the above functionality in svg will help answer all the questions u listed in the first comment. I made some improvements today, and will get back to u with more specific. ur webpages are helpful, and will mark ur comments as a solution if u can move them as answer. Give me some time to go though ur example, and see what can i come up with. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not willing to rewrite an entire example, but here are some resources that might help:

- [Embedding SVG in XHTML5](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml) - includes a simple JavaScript that creates some of the elements programmtically.
- [Dragging Transformed Elements](http://phrogz.net/SVG/drag_under_transformation.xhtml) - uses my own dragging code and accounts for translations in transformed hierarchies.
- [SVGPan](http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/) - a nice library for panning and zooming
- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) - a library designed to create SVG/VML (for old IE) from JavaScript, including its own draggable implementation.
- [KevLinDev](http://www.kevlindev.com/) - a venerable but incredibly-rich source of tutorials and code related to SVG.

Comment: thanks.. I just posted another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862561/svg-script-inside-or-outside  which u may be in good position to answer..