# JavaScript embedded in SVG blocked when displayed in iOS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, svg

I have a HTML5 page that calls an SVG file via `object`:

```
<object data="cape.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
</object>
```

Inside the SVG file is a basic image plus some JavaScript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1200 450"   
 xml:space="preserve">
 <script>
 alert("Test");
 </script>
 <image overflow="visible" width="1200" height="450" xlink:href="cape-reinga.jpg">
 </image>
 </svg>
```

On desktop browsers, including Safari, the JavaScript in the SVG file works as expected. On mobile, the JS seems to be completely ignored. (Wrapping the JS code in `CDATA` makes no difference, adding `type="text/javascript"` makes no difference).

Inlining the SVG is likely not an option for what I have planned: any idea why embedding the JS code in an `object` would prove so troublesome in iOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because javascript in your image data seems like a terrible idea. Why would this be needed?

Comment: @AlexWayne seems like a perfectly reasonable idea, if the script relates directly to the SVG, e.g. animation.  Here's a [good question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862561/svg-script-element-inside-or-outside) that explains applicable scenarios.

Comment: Is this still an issue? On iOS 8.1.3, I can interact with [this SVG](http://apike.ca/media/svg/exampleJavascript.svg) (taken from [here](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_jsanim.html)) just fine with both Safari and Chrome (v 40.0.2214.73).

Comment: @JarrodDixon You're right. a year and a half of hindsight tells me that was a harsh judgement and a snotty attitude. :P