# jQuery is being loaded, however, i get a "$ is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i programming a game for an assignment and i have been trying to implement keystrokes. I have managed to do so in most cases, although sometimes i get this error even though i load jquery properly (i think).
Any idea of what might be wrong here?

```html
<svg width=1300 height=900>

<image x=0 y=0 width=670 height=900 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/firstscreen.png />
<a id="single" xlink:href=http://localhost/cgi-bin/jogo?g>
<image x=200 y=400 width=400 height=150 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/start_button.png />
</a>
<a id="double" xlink:href=http://localhost/cgi-bin/jogo?h>
<image x=200 y=600 width=400 height=150 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/hscores.png />
</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = document.getElementById('single').href.animVal;
     }
    if(e.keyCode == 8) {
      e.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = document.getElementById('double').href.animVal;
     }
   });
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why do you have the `<script>...</script>`  inside a `<svg>...</svg>` tag?

Comment: @t0mm13b i didn't think it would make any difference, and it works most of the time.. should i leave it out of the svg?

Comment: @t0mm13b That's a valid thing to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862561/svg-script-element-inside-or-outside#5862758

Comment: Sure, but you have to reference the external file correctly (via `xlink:href`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862750/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are including jQuery library inside `SVG` Tags,

So jQuery library outside of `SVG` code tags:

**Try this:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width=1300 height=900>

<image x=0 y=0 width=670 height=900 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/firstscreen.png />
<a id="single" xlink:href=http://localhost/cgi-bin/jogo?g>
<image x=200 y=400 width=400 height=150 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/start_button.png />
</a>
<a id="double" xlink:href=http://localhost/cgi-bin/jogo?h>
<image x=200 y=600 width=400 height=150 xlink:href=http://localhost/images/hscores.png />
</a>
<script>
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = document.getElementById('single').href.animVal;
     }
    if(e.keyCode == 8) {
      e.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = document.getElementById('double').href.animVal;
     }
   });
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: you are correct, i thought i had tested this possibility before, sorrry for wasting your time guys. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JoséPedroPinto Glad you get the solution, BTW you can mark this answer as useful so that it helps others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery are not being loaded on the DOM before you try to use it. you can try this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
         if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = document.getElementById('single').href.animVal;
         }
         if(e.keyCode == 8) {
             e.preventDefault();
             window.location.href = document.getElementById('double').href.animVal;
         }
    });
});
```